# select an element from a custom column from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, lambda, entities

I am trying to implement Searching for a custom element in a list with  a custom column name using a webservice for JQgrid, but I am out of ideas I would appreciate any help on this.

I can't copy my code here but, for example, I have an entity like:

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Nationality {get; set;}
}
```

and I created a function to return a list of this class:

```
public static List <Test> getList()
{
    List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
    Test testList1 = new Test();

    testList1.ID = 123;
    testList1.Name = "asd";
    testList1.Nationality = "qwe";

    testList.Add(testList1);
    return testList;
}
```

and from the querystring I get the searchField and searchString, I have stored these values in strings searchField and searchString.

I want something to work similar to this function (I know its wrong but I want that functionality):

```
list=testList.Where(x=>x.searchField.Contains(searchString));
```

I have no problem with getting the list or anything but I just want something similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reflection`:

```
list = testList.Where(x => (x.GetType()
              .GetProperty(searchField)
              .GetValue(x) as string).Contains(searchString)    
     );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it says the .GetValue() doesn't have an overload method that Takes 1 argument ..

Comment: @OmarAs'hab: if you use .Net 4.0 you can use `GetValue(x, null)`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, but i had to change it from
    as string to .ToString().

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it like the following.

```
if(searchField == "ID")
{
   testList = testList.Where(x => x.ID == searchString);
}
else if (searchField == "Name")
{
   testList = testList.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString);
}
else if (searchField == "Nationality")
{
   testList = testList.Where(x => x.Nationality.Contains(searchString);
}
```

Comment: This would work thank you, but the problem is that in the class i have so many attributes to be used, and i have a lot of other classes as well, so i wanted a simple and quick method.